# Knockoutjs not updating on lastest version of Edge

Tags: css, knockout.js, microsoft-edge

I have a knockoutjs app which has been running smoothly for years now. The browser receives a message via SignalR and then is rendered by Knockoutjs.

Now if you run the app in Microsoft Edge, the same fields are not updating on screen where as other fields are updating. It is always the same fields that update once, then never update again. If you inspect the DOM then you can see this being changed.

After a lot of process of elimination, I have actually discovered that the issue seems to be caused by 1 line of css

```
html { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

I have put together a small demo of this bug which you can then run in Chrome/FF/IE9/IE10 vs Edge. Run the code in Edge with the style applied, then comment it out to see the values updating.

http://jsbin.com/baqozusuge/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Link to code on github https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de7610c341e6ee737d8290eb608afb57

Anyone any idea what the heck is going on with this?! It seems as though Microsoft Edge is deciding to cache the display based on the similarity of the value currently displaying.

Comment: It is most definitely a peculiar issue! Edge is not perfect, that really seems like a redraw issue - when appending some Math.random() to each property of cld, it updates it every time, but without it, even calling ko valueHasMutated() doesn't help. And I've also noticed that the interval is not always updating the random value. No idea why text-transform on html fixes it ;(

Comment: Yeah it is as though because of text-transform to uppercase, Edge is comparing the values to decide if it needs to redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is officially a Microsoft bug so something that cannot be "fixed" through code. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7451374/